# Find the rightmost triangle with respect to the diagonal in a four-sided polygon.

Tags: geometry, matlab

The goal is to find the right triangle, depicted in red, in a four-sided polygon with respect to the diagonal. The four-sided polygon's vertices are known.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Initial attempts: The angle formed by the diagonal and the positive x-axis is calculated. I used x1 of v1 > x1 of v3 to identify the red triangle if the angle was found within the first quadrant.

Comment: You should find the leftmost vertex of quadrilateral (which $x$ is minimal) and exclude it.

Comment: This condition will not be sufficient as it can be seen from the last figure.

Comment: If both triangles have all $x$ from $a$ to $b$, how one can say that one of them is righter than another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a line parallel to the given diagonal from both of the other two points, and determine which one has an x-intercept greater than the other.